# How to sort records in a form in decending order from joined query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

The below code is suppose to create a query and feed form 'frmstaticdatadepartments08'  I am trying to sort the records in descending order based on the field tblContacts.TotalTeamSkills.  Unfortunately the sort is not working.

```
 sql_get = "SELECT tblContacts.Group, tblTeams.ID as TeamID, tblValueChain01.MacroProcess, tblTeams.Team, tblContacts.CompleteName, tblContacts.Foto, tblContacts.CurrentPosition, tblContacts.Level, tblContacts.ContractType, tblContacts.Beginner, tblContacts.SemiSkilled, tblContacts.HighlySkilled, tblContacts.Expert, tblContacts.totalskills, tblContacts.TeamBeginner, tblContacts.TeamSemiSkilled, tblContacts.TeamHighlySkilled, tblContacts.TeamExpert, tblContacts.TeamTotalSkills, tblContacts.DeptBeginner, tblContacts.DeptSemiSkilled, tblContacts.DeptHighlySkilled, tblContacts.DeptExpert, tblContacts.DeptTotalSkills, tblContacts.TotalActiveSkills, tblContacts.TotalTeamSkills, tblContacts.TotalDeptSkills, tblcontacts.flag1, tblcontacts.flag2, " & _
    "tblcontacts.JobTitle FROM tblJobTitles INNER JOIN ((tblContacts INNER JOIN tblTeams ON tblContacts.Team = tblTeams.ID) INNER JOIN tblValueChain01 ON tblContacts.Group = tblValueChain01.IDMacroProcesso) ON tblJobTitles.jobtitle = tblContacts.JobTitle WHERE ([tblvaluechain01].[macroprocess]= '" & cboTeams.Value & "') or ([tblcontacts].[group]= 38 and [tblteams].[team]= '" & cboDepartments.Value & "') ORDER BY tblContacts.TotalTeamSkills DESC;"
    Me.frmstaticdatadepartments08.Form.RecordSource = sql_get
```

Comment: if you copy the sql into the sql view of a query, does it produce the results you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't getting any sort of an error message my money is on the fact that your `frmstaticdatadepartments08` already has a `Order By` field.  Put it into design view and look at the forms `Properties` pane which you can open using `Alt + Enter` if it isn't open.  If there is anything set to be sorted in there delete it.

Also, that naming scheme... please fix it for future you.

Comment: Yes I was thinking the same and checked that. Unfortunately, it still is not working. What are you referring to with the 'naming scheme'?

Comment: Strangely, it seems to be sorting in ascending order-

Comment: I found it..  Thank you for the lead. It was in the form properties.

Comment: @MarcheseIlChihuahua No, problem Glad I could help.  And by naming scheme I mean frmstaticdatadepartments08 instead of something like `frmStaticDataDepartments08` or `frmStaticDataDepts08`.